# UTType creation in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, types

I know certain UT types (like `kUTTypeJPEG`, for example) conform to `kUTTypeImage`. What if I wanted to declare my own UTType (`kUTTypeMyImage`, for example) and make existing UTTypes (like `kUTTypeJPEG`, as I said before) conform to it so that `UTTypeConformsTo(existingUTType, kUTTypeMyImage)` returns TRUE?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your application's info.plist.

Apple Documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1

You'll want to pay close attention to `UTTypeConformsTo` as that's the key property to set.

Comment: I think setting it in your own info.plist as an imported UTI would only work if the UTI isn't available elsewhere on the system as an exported UTI (exported UTIs take precedence over imported UTIs).

Comment: This docs say for _mac_ apps.. Does that apply to iOS apps as well?